# Add Prompt to UINavigationBar Programmatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, prompt

How do I programmatically make my UINavigationBar (which doesn't have a UINavigationController) have a prompt whom's text value equals `webTitle`.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = webTitle;
```

The only way I have been able to create a prompt is by applying the following settings onto the NavigationBar in IB.

[image: Yeah]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Proper way is

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Hello";
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming your UINavigationBar belongs to whatever has the webTitle variable.  Let's say the UINavigationBar exists as a property called navigationBar, then you can use this

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.prompt = webTitle;
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. The other one is a hack, imo.

Comment: Also if you have a uinaviagioncontroller, it would just be self.navigationItem.prompt = webTitle